# SPARQL trying to query product availability

Tags: sparql, jena, schema.org, microdata

I am trying to query the availability of a product using the following SPARQL but I always get `null` for `?productAvailable` eventhough the availability is listed as `InStock` in the page I am trying to extract the data from  , I am using Apache Jena API.

I am extracting the triples from the following page .What am I doing wrong ?

http://www.crutchfield.com/p_500SWA10S4/Alpine-SWA-10S4.html

```
SELECT DISTINCT  ?productAvailable ?productUnAvailable WHERE
        {
        ?p2 <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> s:Product .
        ?p2 <http://schema.org/Product/offers> ?schOffer .

        OPTIONAL
          { ?schOffer s:availability ?productAvailable .
            ?productAvailable <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> s:InStock
          }
        OPTIONAL
          { ?schOffer s:availability ?productUnAvailable .
            ?productUnAvailable <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> s:OutOfStock
          }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I extract the data from that page using the [Microdata to RDF Distiller](http://www.w3.org/2012/pyMicrodata/), the relevant bit looks like the following:

```
<> a schema:Product;
    schema:name "Alpine SWA-10S4"@en;
    schema:description "BassLine Series 10\" 4-ohm subwoofer"@en;
    schema:offers [ a schema:Offer;
            schema:availability schema:InStock; ] .
```

If you look at the triple

```
_:offerBNode schema:availability schema:InStock .
```

schema:InStock is used as the object not an instance of it. Thus you don't need the following,

```
{ 
 ?schOffer s:availability ?productAvailable .
 ?productAvailable <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> s:InStock
}
```

All you need is the following pattern

```
?schOffer s:availability s:InStock .
```

For example, you can use a query like

```
PREFIX s: <http://schema.org/>

SELECT DISTINCT  ?productName ?availabity  WHERE
{
  ?p a s:Product;
     s:name ?productName;
     s:offers ?offer .
  ?offer s:availability ?availabity .   
}
```

[This tool](http://librdf.org/query?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2012%2FpyMicrodata%2Fextract%3Furi%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.crutchfield.com%252Fp_500SWA10S4%252FAlpine-SWA-10S4.html%26format%3Dturtle&query=PREFIX%20s%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0ASELECT%20DISTINCT%20%20%3FproductName%20%3Favailabity%20%3Fdes%0D%0A%20%20WHERE%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fp%20a%20s%3AProduct%3B%0D%0A%09%20%20%20s%3Aname%20%3FproductName%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20s%3Aoffers%20%3Foffer%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Foffer%20s%3Aavailability%20%3Favailabity%20.%20%20%20%0D%0A%7D&language=sparql&Run%20Query=Run%20Query&.cgifields=json&.cgifields=raw) might be quite useful for you too to check your query. You can use the distilled page and run test SPARQL queries using that.

Comment: Thanks @Nandana , I realized that after posting this query, but I still do not know if ?availability is s:InStock or s:OutOfStock , is there a way to check if ?availability is equal to s:InStock or s:OutOfStock ? Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks I was able to do that by adding a filter clause .